# I don't know why the navbar is not fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have put together a landing page with Bootstrap and for some reason, the navbar is not fixed.  Below is the code for the navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-inverse bg-primary navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
<div class="container">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right mr-10" href="#">Aquastars Swimming  School</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you used your browser to inspect element to see how CSS styles are being applied?

Comment: When I scroll the Navbar scrolls and is not fixed.

Comment: @AltBrian You have missed `navbar-fixed-top` class man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, as you are using bootstrap 4.
you can seen the working demo of your code here [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gudboisgn/pen/zdZYdW)

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-inverse bg-primary navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
<div class="container">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right mr-10" href="#">Aquastars Swimming  School</a>
</div>
</nav>
```